# PhoneGAP Geoloaction NOT WORKING in Android

Tags: html, cordova, geolocation

Am working in HTML5 + PhoneGap.
In My application i need to impalement Geolocation for get the Latitude and Longitude.

When i search I got the example code from [PhoneGap Website](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/cordova_geolocation_geolocation.md.html)

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// Cordova is ready
//
function onDeviceReady() {
  alert('deviceready');
    //navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess);
}

// onSuccess Geolocation
//

function onSuccess(position) {
    var element = document.getElementById('geolocation');
    element.innerHTML = 'Latitude: '           + position.coords.latitude              + '<br />' +
                        'Longitude: '          + position.coords.longitude             + '<br />' +
                        'Altitude: '           + position.coords.altitude              + '<br />' +
                        'Accuracy: '           + position.coords.accuracy              + '<br />' +
                        'Altitude Accuracy: '  + position.coords.altitudeAccuracy      + '<br />' +
                        'Heading: '            + position.coords.heading               + '<br />' +
                        'Speed: '              + position.coords.speed                 + '<br />' +
                        'Timestamp: '          +                                   position.timestamp          + '<br />';
}

// onError Callback receives a PositionError object
//
function onError(error) {
    alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
            'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
}
```

But Its not working !!
It always Shows **Watching geolocation...** But Details are not loading. 
I have searched this issue and i didnt get a correct solution for this.

I found same issue posted here but that solutions are not woking in this :(

How can I get the details of Latitude and Longitude details using PhoneGap ?

Anybody can Help me???

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue about a year ago and my solution was to reboot my phone - One X Android 4.0 at the time. Can't remember the phonegap version but was a perfect example of why I shouldn't have used phonegap.

If this doesn't work the problem might be with the high accuracy option: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.1.0/cordova_geolocation_geolocation.md.html#Geolocation
Try switching enableHighAccuracy to false/true.

Comment: Yeah I tried navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError, {enableHighAccuracy:true} ); but still not working :(

Answer (score 0):

Some Android devices and emulators only support high or low GPS accuracy.

Try running your code with both low and high accuracy.

```
function onDeviceReady() {
  var options = { enableHighAccuracy: true }; // also try with false.
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError, options);
}
```

If this doesn't work, try tweaking the timeout in options, and finally maybe you haven't set the GPS permissions on your Android project properly. Check the app manifest to see what permissions you do or don't have set.

Comment: Hi..@David Rust-Smith  I already set all the permissions in app/res/xml/config.xml and app/AndroidManifest.xml . But its not working :(

Comment: I goes through the http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.7.0/cordova_geolocation_geolocation.md.html#Geolocation

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason is we always use the browser's html5 implementation not native.Try to make sure you are using the cordova native function to locate the postion.